# Disable jquery-chosen on touchmove to enable scroll on page

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

If you touch a chosen (https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) drop-down container while you scroll on any mobile device (like an iPad) the menu will pop out and you won´t be able to scroll the page.

I tried modifying the code, by commenting out two lines and moving  _this.container_mousedown(evt); like this:

```
this.container.on('touchstart.chosen', (function(_this) {
                return function(evt) {
                    //_this.container_mousedown(evt);
                };
            })(this));
            this.container.on('touchend.chosen', (function(_this) {
                return function(evt) {
                    _this.container_mousedown(evt);
                    //_this.container_mouseup(evt);
                };
            })(this));
```

It makes it possible to scroll, but the first touch event/click doesn´t work. The drop-down only flickers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it by only commenting out

```
//_this.container_mousedown(evt);
```

in the `this.container.on('touchstart.chosen'` -event.

The action is triggered by the mousedown event anyway. Though this causes a delay of 300ms when opening.